# Cascade delete when i set it to false is not working in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

Previously when creating a migration the cascade delete was set to true and then updated the database. I honestly did not notice that cascading elimination was set to true.
After several migrations applied to the database, I need to set the cascade delete to false but it is not working, because it continues to cascade deletion.

This is the one-to-many relationship i made, where a customer can have many vehicles and a vehicle belongs to one customer:

This is my Customer class:

```
public class Customer {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public List<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }

    public Customer()
    {
        Vehicles = new List<Vehicle>();
    }
}
```

This is my Vehicle class:

```
public class Vehicle {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Enrollment{ get; set; }
    public string Chassis { get; set; }
    public float? Kilometers{ get; set; }
    public int? CylinderCapacity{ get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId{ get; set; }
}
```

And this is my Fluent API configuration:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>()
        .HasRequired(v => v.Customer)
        .WithMany(c => c.Vehicles)
        .HasForeignKey(v => v.CustomerId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);    
}
```

And the migration class is this:

```
public partial class DisableDeleteOnCascade : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Vehicles", "CustomerId", "dbo.Customers");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Vehicles", "CustomerId", "dbo.Customers", "Id");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Vehicles", "CustomerId", "dbo.Customers");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Vehicles", "CustomerId", "dbo.Customers", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
    }
}
```

For some reason when i delete a customer is still deleting  the vehicles, and i don't want that behaviour. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Do you build project? u should build or re-build project and re-execute. I think u should clean state of ef

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/jan/13/resetting-entity-framework-migrations-to-a-clean-slate